# Saving attributes to an object in Python

Tags: python

I'm practicing OOP concepts in Python, and I came across this problem:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, username, email, password, 
        firstname, lastname, phone):

        self.username = ""
        self.email = ""
        self.password = ""
        self.firstname = ""
        self.lastname = ""
        self.phone = ""

user=User('x','y','z','f','v','c')
print(vars(user))
```

Result:

```
{'username': '', 'firstname': '', 'lastname': '', 'phone': '', 'password': '', 'email': ''}
```

The values are not saved to the object. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the function arguments to the instance variables.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, username, email, password, 
        firstname, lastname, phone):

        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.phone = phone

user=User('x','y','z','f','v','c')
print(vars(user))
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the constructor arguments to the appropriate instance variables:

```
def __init__(self, username, email, password, firstname, lastname, phone):
    self.username = username
    # etc.
```